# Is there any official reason why OSX does not have a native package manager?

Tags: macos, mac, homebrew

I’m new in the OSX world, after a few search on internet, I realized that all package managers for OSX are 3rd party tools.
OSX as a Unix-based system, I just can’t imagine that Apple hasn’t thought about a built-in package manager.

1. **Is there any reason why Apple didn’t provide a packet manager ?**
2. **Does Apple (officially or not) support one of the existing 3rd party package managers ?** *I heard that the author of Homebrew is now working for Apple*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's primary audience are not command line users.

Apple provide the Mac App Store for distribution and updating of both their own and third party software. The store can be reached through **Applications > App Store.app**.

With regard to the history of [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_management_software)) and [Max Howell](https://twitter.com/mxcl)'s employment by Apple, Max has since left Apple.