# No package manager on brand new macOS Catalina

Tags: terminal, bash, catalina, zsh, package-management

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I've been searching for days with no results.

What is the default package manager for macOS Catalina terminal?

```
% brew
zsh: command not found: brew
```

I've tried others (apt, apt-get, yum, etc.) but none of them are pre-installed. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any official reason why OSX does not have a native package manager?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258365/is-there-any-official-reason-why-osx-does-not-have-a-native-package-manager)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only package manager that’s somewhat default is `/usr/bin/easy_install`  for python. You have to choose and install any of the leading open source type package managers.

For [brew](https://brew.sh/), this has been the command to download and run code from the internet.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

If this thought makes you cringe, [alternate install paths are safer](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation) than trusting dns and scripts without having a chance to inspect them.

```
mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```